# how to install filter Plugin for grails?

Tags: plugins, grails, filter, installation

I am Trying to install grails filter-0.2 plug in.when i run **install-plugin filter**.It starts installing but when it displays resolving filter plug in please wait..at that time installation terminates with out giving any error message.

Why is that So.Can any one answer me.

With Advance Thanks,
laxmi

Answer (score 0):

I have tried install the filter plugin(`grails install-plugin filter`) without any trouble. I think that there maybe some problem with your repositories. You should try to create a blank app(by `grails create-app`) and try installing again.

Comment: now i have installed it..but now my problem is when i run my app  i am getting error as**Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <filter:dynamic>: Cannot get property 'persistentProperties' on null object **

Comment: @laxmi: What is the trouble code? Please give more information.